# convert F10.11 to F1011 in excel

Tags: excel

I have bunch of cells having codes like:

F10.11, F10.120, F10.121 etc. I want to remove the decimal from these codes and display without decimal.

Is there a way to convert F10.11 to F1011 in excel? I tried formatting the cell but nothing is helpful.

Comment: Use the replace tool and replace all the `.` with nothing.

Comment: lol thanks that was quick!

Comment: Just be careful in replacing ALL the decimal points in the spreadsheet. You might want to keep some.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `SUBSTITUTE`. like this: `=SUBSTITUE(A2;",";"")`, where A2 contains your text.
Or rely on Find & Replace (ctrl+h).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @scott Craner for the suggestion. The quickest way is to do Cntrl+F and in the Replace box replace '.' with nothing and it worked!